# solved: HTML checked checkboxes in a FORM to a file.txt PHP

Tags: php

So I have a Form with Check Boxes and When I submit the form I want the values of the boxes that are selected to be sent to a text file?

**Question:** How do I know what boxes are selected and then retrieve those values?

this is my form, it is all automated once someone selects a value from a drop down box

```
echo '<form action="test.php" method="post">'
sqlCheckbox();
echo '<input type="submit" value="save to text file" name="Save To Text File"'
echo '</form>
```

sqlCheckbox() does this for each result

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="SQL_QUERY">SQL_QUERY <br>'
```

**I found the solution**, this is what i fixed/did.
change 1: changed my checkbox name to an array ([] at the end of name)
change 2: once the submit is clicked it goes to my test.php page
here is my other page code

```
<?php 
echo "saved to file";
$array = $_POST['check'];
information = "";//Justin for the variable Idea

foreach ($array $value) {//turns out only the checked checked boxes get submitted
    $information .= $value . "<br>";
}

$file = "test.txt" //Flo draven had this idea
file_put_contents($file, $information, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

this saves the values that were selected and sends them to the test.txt file, so I now have my sql queries in a text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
$file = fopen("test.txt","w");
echo fwrite($file,"Hello World. Testing!");
fclose($file);
?>
```

instead of "Hello World" , take the contents of your checkboxes.

you can of course define a variable with the path to any file you want to put the contents into.

a better option probably would be :

```
<?php
$file = 'people.txt';
// The new person to add to the file
$person = "John Smith\n";
// Write the contents to the file, 
// using the FILE_APPEND flag to append the content to the end of the file
// and the LOCK_EX flag to prevent anyone else writing to the file at the same time
file_put_contents($file, $person, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

Comment: That all makes sense, but for some reason I cant grasp how to get the values of each check box submitted, do i do a $_POST on the form? because each value is about a paragraph long.

Answer (score 0):

Check out using fopen and fclose on the [Php Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php). That opens a file, then you will be able to send the data to it and save it.

Comment: Thats what I am having trouble with, I am unsure how to transfer the values to the text file, should I create an array with the values? or just store them into a variable then send the variable to the text file

Comment: Do the latter. Put the checkbox values into a variable and have those sent to the text file.

Comment: use simply csv for that. It provide easy work with data.

Comment: Also, you might want to update your question with more specific details, such as what exactly the problem your having and need help with is, and what you have tried so we know what exactly you need.

Comment: @Justin sorry, here is more accurate details of what i want to achieve